# Gold-standard drill make?

Tags: drill, powertools

Craftsman:wrenches as BLANK:power drills

What is the gold-standard power drill make? For general purposes/light carpentry.

Comment: You misspelled Snap-On.

Comment: Emphatically not Craftsman power; tools, anyway. They 're generally label-engineered low-end Black&Decker models. And, yeah, the Craftsman warranty is excellent but there's nothing special about the quality of theit hand tools. REMINDER: that warranty does _not_ apply to power tools or torque wrenches; there may be other exceptions I'm not aware of.

Comment: Gold standard and "general purposes/light carpentry" don't really match. As @Tyler Durden noted, there are really good (ie, "gold standard") options out there. For mere mortals, decent Dewalt/ Milwaukee/ Makita/ Bosch should provide good service. Just avoid the low end ones with plastic gears (drills, specifically).

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking any manufacturer can make a high-quality drill if they want. Large manufacturers often do not because the number they would sell would be so small as to make no difference to their balance sheet.

Milwaukee makes good "contractor-quality" drills, like their "magnum" 1/2" drill, that you can find in trade shops.

There are two premium tool makers: Fein and Festool. Their tools cost 2 to 3 times what a Milwaukee costs. The differences, which are mostly convenience features, in my opinion do not justify the extra expense.

Note that you can "upgrade" a standard drill like a Milwaukee by taking it apart and replacing and aligning the bearings. A typical drill will have 3 rotary bearings. You can replace those bearing with much more expensive bearings and make sure that the alignment is perfect. You can always pay a machinist to do the same thing. Prepare to spend thousands.